# How to avoid this awful Mypy syntax?

Tags: python, mypy

I want to set the type of `f` as `typing.IO[typing.Any]`.  The code below gets that done, but putting typing code in a comment rubs me wrong.

```
with open(cache_file) as f:  # type: typing.IO[typing.Any]
    cache_dict = json.load(f)
```

Is there any other syntax available for this situation where a colon immediately follows the variable I want to set the type for?  I was hoping for something like this:

```
   with open(cache_file) as f: typing.IO[typing.Any]:
        cache_dict = json.load(f)
```